# Google Sheets - IMPORTDATA ISSUE- Frequency of refresh and a way to control it?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the `IMPORTDATA` function to call the SEMrush API and the initial pull is fine. The problem is that it continues to "randomly" call the API (which costs $).

```
 Timing of API queries:         
    Time    IP  Report type Query
    18:11:16 02.08.2016 66.249.89.91    backlinks_overview  100layercake.com
    18:11:14 02.08.2016 46.229.161.160  domain_rank www.100layercake.com
    17:55:31 02.08.2016 66.249.89.91    backlinks_overview  100layercake.com
    17:55:28 02.08.2016 46.229.161.160  domain_rank www.100layercake.com
    17:41:14 02.08.2016 46.229.161.160  domain_rank www.100layercake.com
    17:41:15 02.08.2016 66.249.89.91    backlinks_overview  100layercake.com
    16:50:47 02.08.2016 66.249.89.91    backlinks_overview  100layercake.com
    16:50:45 02.08.2016 46.229.161.160  domain_rank www.100layercake.com
```

The 2 calls at 16:50 are mine from initial setup. Everything after that has occurred automatically. No one else is in the sheet and the importdata is the only function on the sheet.

I have read through so many boards and have seen conflicting information, so my questions are:

1. Does Google cache the information and if so, for how long (or is there somewhere that can tell me this)?
2. Is there a way to control this?

Another twist while testing this after first noticing the problem - I actually deleted the sheet I was using to stop the issue. SEMrush continued to show API queries for hours after that until SEMrush support changed the key.

I've been beating my head against the desk on this one, trying to figure out if I've done something wrong so if someone can assist, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!
Amy

Comment: This site is for programming questions, but this sounds like a problem for technical support. You might also try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

From [Change a spreadsheet's locale, time zone, recalculation, and language](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en)

> Note: External data functions recalculate at the following intervals:
>
> - ImportRange: 30 minutes
> - ImportHtml, ImportFeed, ImportData, ImportXml: 1 hour
> - GoogleFinance: may be delayed up to 20 minutes

Sometime after the original post of this answer Google updated the linked article and could do this again without notice. To learn the current wording and recalculation intervales follow the above link.