# How to update IMPORTDATA more frequently than just once an hour in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having issues with google sheets only updating the queried importdata ONCE AN HOUR no matter how many different ways I try to override it through apps script...my setting are on update once a minute and I have an appscript that triggers the code below once a minute.

See code below. Other forums recommended the SpreadsheetApp.flush() function after cutting and pasting the query formula...but for some reason sheets still seems to retain the aged data. It only updates at the top of the hour.

So I attempted to clear the cached data, but that seems to do absolutely nothing. It still retains the same data and will only update once an hour.

Does Sheets have a limitation on refreshing data, or am I doing something wrong here?

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('M1').setValue('');
CacheService.getDocumentCache().removeAll;
CacheService.getUserCache().removeAll;
CacheService.getScriptCache().removeAll;
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('M1').setValue('=query(IMPORTDATA("https://api.marketinout.com/run/backtest?key=bee65ce8674143d2","|"), "Select * limit 100")');
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

UPDATE:

I found this comment in another stack conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38754257/18737653

Basically it confirms that Sheets only pulls external data every hour. Is there any way to bypass this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXdUI.png)

Comment: have you set a trigger? triggers can be set to run as often as every 1 minute.

Comment: Yes I set a trigger for my appscript at 1-minute intervals. The function runs every minute and I can see it delete the formula and replace the formula in the cell. But it does not actually pull fresh data from the API source.